# Matlab sort every other column

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

I've got data that looks like this in a repeating pattern-

```
years cf1  years  cf2
2010   45  2010   37
2011   39  2011   29
2012   51  2012   31
2013   25  2013   33 
2014   35  2014   28
```

I need the data or array to look like this after every other column is sorted by the "cfX" variable.

```
years cf1  years cf2
2013  25   2014  28
2014  35   2011  29
2011  39   2012  31
2010  45   2013  33
2012  51   2010  37
```

thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each set of two columns, you can use `sortrows`.

```
for idx=1:2:size(M,2)
    M(:,idx:idx+1)=sortrows(M(:,idx:idx+1),2)
end
```

Comment: Hi- is "M" the 5 row by 4 col array that I've given above in unsorted form?

Comment: @user2100039 - Wasn't my post :) It was Daniel.  I just happened to be around to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

### Vectorized approach

This assumes `A` to be the input matrix.

```
[m,n] = size(A);  %// size of input matrix
[~,id] = sort(A(:,2:2:end),1); %// sorted IDs

%// Use id to get linear indices of all elements based on asked sorting criteria
%// and index into A for the final output
Aout = A(bsxfun(@plus,reshape(repmat(permute(id,[1 3 2]),1,2),m,n),[0:n-1]*m));
```

The last line can be replaced by the following code, which seems to be giving marginal runtime improvements for small datasizes -

```
Aout = A(bsxfun(@plus,reshape(repmat(id,2,1),m,n),[0:n-1]*m));
```

### Benchmarking

This section benchmarks the proposed vectorized approach against loop based approach listed in [@Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28116583/3293881) and [late addition by @Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28118991/3293881).

**Benchmarking code**

```
%// Random huge input array
A = rand(10000);

disp('----------------------------------------  With vectorized approach')
tic
[m,n] = size(A);  %// size of input matrix
[~,id] = sort(A(:,2:2:end),1); %// sorted IDs

%// Use id to get linear indices of all elements based on asked sorting criteria 
Aout = A(bsxfun(@plus,reshape(repmat(permute(id,[1 3 2]),1,2),m,n),[0:n-1]*m));
toc
clear Aout m n id

disp('----------------------------------------  With loop based approach')
tic
Aout2 = zeros(size(A));
for idx=1:2:size(A,2)
    Aout2(:,idx:idx+1)=sortrows(A(:,idx:idx+1),2);
end
toc
clear Aout2 idx

disp('----------------------------------------  With Luis Vectorized approach')
tic
[m, n] = size(A);
[~, rows] = sort(A(:,2:2:n)); %// indices to sort columns 2, 4,...
ind = bsxfun(@plus, rows, (0:n/2-1)*2*m); %// convert to linear index
y = NaN(m,n);
y(:,2:2:n) = A(ind+m); %// fill columns 2, 4,... sorted
y(:,1:2:n) = A(ind);  %// fill columns 1, 3,... with the same order
toc
```

**Runtimes**

```
----------------------------------------  With vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 2.244272 seconds.
----------------------------------------  With loop based approach
Elapsed time is 3.255867 seconds.
----------------------------------------  With Luis Vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 2.800249 seconds.
```

Comment: Nice vectorized approach! I had independently wrote another one; I hope it's not too similar

Comment: @LuisMendo No I think and I like yours too!

Comment: Thanks for adding me to the benchmarking. Your code wins! The results are similar on my machine (for slightly smaller matrices)

Comment: @LuisMendo Got rid of that `permute`, but not for any huge improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another vectorized approach. Let `x` denote your matrix.

```
[m, n] = size(x);
[~, rows] = sort(x(:,2:2:n)); %// indices to sort columns 2, 4,...
ind = bsxfun(@plus, rows, (0:n/2-1)*2*m); %// convert to linear index
y = NaN(m,n); %// you can remove this line if `y` is assured not to exist,
              %// because in that case the next line serves as preallocation
y(:,2:2:n) = x(ind+m); %// fill columns 2, 4,... sorted
y(:,1:2:n) = x(ind);  %// fill columns 1, 3,... with the same order
```

Comment: Sweet! Could be faster than mine!

Comment: Any particular reason for using NaNs?

Comment: @Divakar Your code is a little faster on my machine. Those `NaN`s are only for initiallization, they could be zeros; or the line can be safely removed as the next line serves as preallocation

Comment: Added your code timings in my code. You are right, a bit faster.

Comment: A little bit slower than Divakar's solution, but compared to it this solution cut's the memory overhead in half.

Answer (score 2):

Another loop based approach, using only sort:

```
disp('----------------------------------------  With other loop based approach')
tic
Aout3 = zeros(size(A));
for i=0:size(A,2)/2-1
  [ord iord]=sort(A(:,2*i+2),'ascend');
  Aout3(:,2*i+1)=A(iord,2*i+1);
  Aout3(:,2*i+2)=ord;
end
toc
```

Adding this to the [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28118804/4453183), for `A=rand(5000)` I get:

```
----------------------------------------  With vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 1.415872 seconds.
----------------------------------------  With loop based approach
Elapsed time is 1.997568 seconds.
----------------------------------------  With Luis Vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 1.560120 seconds.
----------------------------------------  With other loop based approach
Elapsed time is 1.566022 seconds.
```

Comment: Can you provide some context as to why your answer addresses the question?

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as Daniel provided, but less elegant (no offence).  I don't see how this contributes more than his answer (already accepted).

Comment: This was not the case when I started writing. I was actually wondering about the etiquette in this situation, should I just delete my answer?

Comment: @yoh.lej - no no you can leave it.  This is probably a first principles approach that someone may take :)  Leave it.

Comment: @rayryeng actually seeing the benchmark, I tested my answer and it seems to perform better than the other loop based approach, not as good but almost as good as the vectorized version.

Comment: @yoh.lej - Amend the timing to your post and I think it would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Nice! It could be because `sortrows` seems to be internally using `sort`.

Comment: I didn't really expect it, I was just curious and...I am still trying to figure out why!