# Group by one column and calculate the median for the groups in matlab

Tags: mysql, matlab, optimization, median

I read the following table from mysql into a matlab cell array:

```
Nyse = fetch(conn,'SELECT ticker,date,utcsec,bid,ofr FROM HFE.Quotes where ex="N" order by utcsec,bid;');
```

The Nyse cell array contain 1000000 rows. And I want to calculate the median bid for each second, where the second is recorded as a string in the utcsec column. I do it in the following way:

```
utcsec=cell2mat(Nyse(:,3));
bid=cell2mat(Nyse(:,4));
NyseBid=grpstats(bid,utcsec,{'median'});
```

The problem is that the function grpstats takes around 70 sec to do the task. The question is, how can I optimize the code so it will run faster?

An example string in the UTCSEC column is '09:30:00'.

Comment: One million rows is not a trivial amount of data. Do you only need the median or do you need the other information calculated by `grpstats`?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow the data. What are the dimensions and data types of `utcsec` and `bid`? Is `utcsec` just a time vector?

Comment: utcsec is a vector containg string with the following format '09:30:00','09:30:00','09:30:01' and so on and so forth

Comment: What about `bid`? Is `utcsec` [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)?

Comment: bid is a vector of numbers 2.3, 2.4,4.5,4.6 and so on and so forth. utcsec is monotomic i guess. utcsec is incresing

Comment: If `bid` and `utcsec` are both vectors what exactly do you want to group for each timestamp? There's only one measurement...

Comment: What SQL server are you using? This might possibly done entirely within SQL.

Comment: There is no "median" function in MySQL.  (But it can be done in some clumsy code.)  If the `SELECT` is the slow part, then add `INDEX(ex, utcsec, bid)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you checkout [this question and these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635984/time-series-aggregation-efficiency/33691946#33691946) as it is a highly related problem.

To apply the results of that thread to this problem, I would use [this MEX function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53913-mg-getrowswithkey-cpp) I wrote which takes in an array of groupIDs and extracts which rows each group is on. This allows efficient aggregation by group.

As I understand, utcsec is essentially a groupID and bid is the array to aggregate. The code would go:

```
utcsec = Nyse(:,3);    %utcsec in this should be a cell array o fstrings
[unique_utcsec, map] = mg_getRowsWithKey(utcsec);  %call to my magic function
         %unique_utcsec contains unique strings in utcsec
         %map shows us which rows correspond to each unique second

median_bid = zeros(length(unique_utcsec), size(bid,2));

for i = 1:length(unique_utcsec)  %iterate over each utc second
    median_bid(i,:) = median(bid(map{i},:),1);  %calculate the median for that second
end
```

In my testing, this code is significantly faster than Matlab's implementation with the grpstats function. There are alternative approaches in that thread as well that do not rely on mex. The mex c++ code should be compiled with:

```
mex -largeArrayDims mg_getRowsWithKey.cpp
```

And then the function mg_getRowsWithKey can be called like any Matlab function. mg_getRowsWithKey is written in c++ using STL libraries such as map.

Comment: If you use this approach, I'd love to know what the speedup was.